# AddHandler syntax

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd, localhost

This is my .htaccess file - currently very limited for now, as it's a test site at:

http://localhost/mydomain/testfile

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .$
```

Is this syntax correct so that **any** file can be served extensionless and still run as a PHP one, in theory?

I'm fairly new to this, and would appreciate the help.

Comment: It may not be wise to do this. Why do you need this?

Comment: You really really really shound't do this, it's not a good idea

Comment: Hey, folks, if you're going to tell someone it's not a good idea, it would be great if you could provide some documentation to back that up.  Note that I'm not disagreeing; I just think that data is better than hearsay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<FilesMatch>` directive

```
<Filesmatch "^[^\.]+$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

This can be placed in [several different places](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) depending on the scope that you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AddHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler) documentation, it doesn't appear to accept any sort of wildcard pattern, so I don't think that `.$` is going to do anything other than match files that end with a literal `.$`.

If you want to set a default handler for all files in a directory, you're probably better off with the [SetHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#sethandler) directive.

Keep in mind that if you do something like this, you're limiting yourself to only servering PHP files from this directory...that means no images, no audio, no plain HTML; just PHP.  It's unlikely that this is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1 [T=application/x-httpd-php-source]
```